# Boot screen stuck and does not start

Tags: boot

I had windows10 I tried installing Ubuntu and now the computer can't start was my dad's laptop What should I do now?

Comment: Restore an appropriate backup, which for sure you made right before you started the installation ...

Answer (score 2):

What does "boot screen stuck" mean actually? At least you have to provide us information about what appears ultimately.

Anyways, you can try to do this:

1. Do you still have your Ubuntu live CD? If yes, boot into your live CD and run a live session.
2. Press `Ctrl+Alt+T` to open the terminal.
3. Input `sudo grub-install` to renew your boot configuration.

See if this works.